# WSDL and JAVA in Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Will there be a difference in the generated client stubs when using WSDL with Java 6 Vs Java7? We use CXF framework for WS and using Java 7 gives us the following message: "com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: ". With Java6 it is working fine.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: mhm hard to tell with the details provided (maybe provide a kind of obfuscated stacktrace next time) but maybe https://community.oracle.com/thread/1670964?start=0 helps you.

Comment: Thanks for you response jethroo. I just want to know if there would be any difference in the client stub generated with WSDL using JDK 6 Vs JDK7.